# Choice of Pivot in Quicksort

Tags: algorithm, quicksort

**A desirable choice for the partitioning element in quick sort is**

> (A) First element of the list
>
> (B) Last element of the list
>
> (C) Randomly chosen element of the list
>
> (D) Median of the list

Answer given is (A) but according to me, it should be (D). Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Answer : (D) Median of the list

Every time if we take median as the pivot element  `using partition algorithm it takes O(n) time` .then replace the median with last element(it is a/c to your algorithm means what you have chosen as pivot here I assumed last element as pivot .) it will take `O(1) constant time to replace last element with median`, and every time it divides the problem into 2 half

> T(n) = O(n) + 2T(n/2) solve using master theorem and get complexity as
>   O(nlogn)

In the above  equation `O(n) is in case of Partition algorithm`.

Answer (score 1):

Choosing (A) or (B) would result in Quicksort experiencing its worst case scenario, with an O(n²) time complexity.

Choosing randomly will deviate this bad performance and the algorithm will run effectively.

Choosing the median element will still suffice to prevent the algorithm from performing badly. The problem is that it's a constant factor slower per iteration.

So either (C) or (D) will be fine.

---

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#Choice_of_pivot):

In the very early versions of Quicksort, the leftmost element of the partition would often be chosen as the pivot element. Unfortunately, this causes worst-case behavior on already sorted arrays, which is a rather common use-case. The problem was easily solved by choosing either a random index for the pivot, choosing the middle index of the partition or (especially for longer partitions) choosing the median of the first, middle and last element of the partition for the pivot.

Comment: You appear to be assuming that "choosing the middle" and "choosing the median" are the same. They are not. "Choosing the median" gets the best case, every time. The problem is that it's a constant factor slower per iteration.

Comment: @MooingDuck I didn't notice that, thank you very much for the comment and the upvote! Answer updated.